# Turning an AWS server into a proxy server to be used to crawl with Scrapy

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, proxy, scrapy

I was just wondering if anyone knows how I could configure an Amazon Web Services server to be used by a Scrapy crawler as a proxy server? I don't want to get blacklisted by the websites I am crawling so I need to use proxy servers. I just am not sure how to turn the AWS server into a proxy server. Thank you!!

Comment: If the websites blacklist you, that should be a message that you are violating their terms of service/terms of use.  The solution is simple: don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to proxy your HTTP traffic through an EC2 instance, although not as safe as using [TOR](https://stem.torproject.org/) or an [anonymous vpn](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), is to use [tinyproxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinyproxy). You can find a [walkthrough here](http://www.frankhq.io/blog/2012/11/14/how-to-setup-a-private-proxy-server-on-ec2-in-under-10-minutes/).

Note that scraping in such a way as to violate a website's terms of use or otherwise impact the functionality of their site can be a legal liability if you intentionally violate those terms as per [Trespass to chattels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_chattels).

Comment: The link is broken!
http://www.frankhq.io/blog/2012/11/14/how-to-setup-a-private-proxy-server-on-ec2-in-under-10-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you pay for the traffic and that after too many recurring request from the same IP that IP will be banned.